# Jlabel.setText() only update at the end of the code

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I have a problem, when I try to set the text of my JLabel it only changes after the code ends...
Here's my code:

```
public static void start(String username, String aToken, String uuid) {
    SUpdate su = new SUpdate(...));
    // Some parameters here...
    LauncherPanel.title.setText("Mise à jour du jeu...");
    try {
        su.start();
    } catch (BadServerResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServerDisabledException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadServerVersionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServerMissingSomethingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you need more infos, just ask me

Comment: There's not enough information to answer. If you update the text from an event handler, `JLabel` will be unable to repaint until your handler exists.

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the  `repaint()` method of your `JLabel`, like `LauncherPanel.title.repaint()`.

Comment: It's not working... I put it after the setText, is that the correct way ?

Comment: If launcherPanel is a JComoonent, you can try repaint it too